# Pygame dice roller

Tags: python, pygame

I'd like to have the dice roll, and then player 1 move forward as many spaces as the dice rolls on. Currently, this is the starting code with the grid and the squares along with the numbers.

```
import pygame
import random 

w_in_squares = 7
h_in_squares = 6
square_dim   = 50

blue  = (47,134,150)
white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0,0,0)
red   = (255,0,0)

def Draw_Checker_Board( window, number_font ):
    

    #7x6 checkbaord
    number = 1
    current_colour = white

    for i in range(0, h_in_squares):
        tl_corner_y = i * square_dim     # top-left corner Y coordinate
        for j in range(0, w_in_squares):
            if current_colour == white:
                current_colour = black
            else:
                current_colour = white
            tl_corner_x = j * square_dim  # top-left corner X coordinate

            rectangle = ( tl_corner_x, tl_corner_y, square_dim, square_dim)   # rectangle defining checker
            pygame.draw.rect( window, current_colour, rectangle )             # paint the rectangle
            number_bitmap = number_font.render( str(number), True, blue )     # create the number
            number += 1
        
            margin = 10
            window.blit( number_bitmap, ( tl_corner_x + margin, tl_corner_y + margin ) )
```

Comment: Use a loop that sets `diceroll` and then uses that as the amount to move.

Comment: use dice inside `while True:`. And you will have other code also run in this loop. ie. move players, redraw board, etc.

Comment: "my original code made no sense and bad practice to keep" - your original code may have made no sense, but that doesn't mean you should remove it from the question. The code in a question is supposed to be the code you had a question about, not new code you got out of an answer.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really clear what you need here, the code does not do what's described.  So I've re-arranged it, moved some code into a function, and "made it work" somewhat.

So, to address the changes:

- All constants to be named in capitals.  This is a very common convention in programming.

  - I pushed them all to the same place in the code, too.
- Changed the grid from being 6x7 to 7x6, otherwise you get columns of colour.  If you did want coloured columns, just change that back.
- Moved the drawing of the chequered board pattern into a function
- Reworked the main loop to paint the Board, update the window, limit the frame-rate, etc..

The biggest change is obviously moving the drawing of the board into a function.  This is desirable because it "compartmentalises" *everything* about  drawing a numbered, chequered board into a single place, which can later be called with a single statement.

If the code does not define functions / procedures like this, it would end-up unwieldy, (with probably repeated) lumps of code all over the place.   Either that, or "goto" instructions to branch the program's execution.

Where I think you should go from here:

- Store your player information (`colour`, `position`) in a data structure, say a Python List

  - For example:  `player1 = [ RED, 1 ]`
- Write another function `drawPlayer()` that given a `window` and `player`, "knows" how to draw that player's circle in the correct square by taking elements from the Player data structure (list).

  - Obviously this new `drawPlayer()` function would be called during the main loop, similar to how the Board drawing function is.

Once this part is working OK, *then* look at how you want to implement the dice-rolling.  Please feel free to ask another question at this time.

[image: screen shot]

```
import pygame
import random

W_IN_SQUARES = 7
H_IN_SQUARES = 6
SQUARE_DIM   = 50

BLUE  = (47,134,150)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0,0,0)
RED   = (255,0,0)

def drawCheckerBoard( window, number_font ):
    """ Draw a checker-board alternating-coloured square pattern
        to the given window surface.  Put a number into each square """

    #7x6 checkbaord
    number = 1
    current_colour = WHITE

    for i in range(0, H_IN_SQUARES):
        tl_corner_y = i * SQUARE_DIM      # top-left corner Y coordinate
        for j in range(0, W_IN_SQUARES):
            if current_colour == WHITE:
                current_colour = BLACK
            else:
                current_colour = WHITE
            tl_corner_x = j * SQUARE_DIM  # top-left corner X coordinate

            rectangle = ( tl_corner_x, tl_corner_y, SQUARE_DIM, SQUARE_DIM)   # rectangle defining checker
            pygame.draw.rect( window, current_colour, rectangle )             # paint the rectangle
            number_bitmap = number_font.render( str(number), True, BLUE )     # create the number
            number += 1
            # Space it off the corner a bit
            margin = 10
            window.blit( number_bitmap, ( tl_corner_x + margin, tl_corner_y + margin ) )  # paint the number


"""
#diceroller from 1-6 using random.rantint
diceroll = random.randint(1,6)
rollboard = DiceRollerFont.render(str(diceroll),1,WHITE)
for ex in range(0, W_IN_SQUARES):
    for why in range(0, H_IN_SQUARES):
        drawing_window.blit(rollboard,(310,300))


player1 = pygame.draw.circle(drawing_window,BLUE,(25,25),10)
player1 = pygame.draw.circle(drawing_window,RED,(40,25),10)

"""

pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()

drawing_window = pygame.display.set_mode((350, 350))
drawing_window.fill(BLUE)

# I don't have 'cambriamath'
font = pygame.font.SysFont( None, 18, bold =pygame.font.Font.bold)
dice_roller_font = pygame.font.SysFont('arial', 40)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()   # used to govern the max MAX_FPS
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    # paint the window
    drawCheckerBoard( drawing_window, font )

    # "flush" the changes to the window
    pygame.display.update()

    clock.tick( 60 )   # control the frame-rate to save electricity

pygame.quit()
```